# ArcGIS for Silverlight Print Task

Tags: silverlight, arcgis-server

When I try to use this Export Web Map Task in ArcGIS Server from a Silver-light Application the Server throws this error when a Feature Service is included...

> Error executing tool.: Layer "Site Locations": Missing 'symbol' in
>   simple renderer. Failed to execute (Export Web Map). Failed to execute
>   (Export Web Map Task).

The service contains a very simple symbol. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you inspected the simple renderer and made sure it does have a value for the `Symbol` property?

Comment: Yeah, and it doesn't... It should get it from the server. I tested it with another feature layer and it gets the symbol off the server so I'm not sure whats happening.

Comment: It may be that only certain symbols are supported with the `ExportWebMap` task. We have a similar problem with server-side printing. Check to see if the symbols are different from the service that works, and the service that doesn't.